# Duplicate master to another sheet that auto sorts by the date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can not seem to figure this one out.

I have a master sheet that is sorted by "shows" (this sheet with constantly have updates/changes) I need another sheet that mimics this info but sorts by the date.

display of chart:
[image: display of chart]

Comment: If you can manage the VBA code then I could suggest you bunch of code lines to Copy selected Range and Paste then Sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply with a table. If you don't want to create a mirror of that data onto another sheet, you could simply make the data you have into a Table (Highlight all of the appropriate cells, go to the "Insert" ribbon and click "Table"). You could then sort it any way you'd like on the spot.